# MySQL Query showing certain duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

I would love some help with a MySQL query.
I want a query that will show me duplicates in my table.
So, for each userid, show me rows that have the same date field but only if fieldx is not unique.
I don't mind a user having two or more records with the same date so long as fieldx is unique between these rows.
So a query like...
select * from table where same date shows up more than once (for a given user) and fieldx is the same (for that user).
Thanks!
seabro

Comment: Show your table structure and some sample data to make it easier to answer.

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 0):

Sean, you can try something like this

```
select `field_name` from `table_name` group by `field_name` having count(*)>=2
```

you have to replace the field_name and table_name with your actual field_name(pass the field name which you want to check the duplicate) and table_name